# linq to sql with two conditions

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I want to write `linq to sql` query with two `where` conditions,
But in all conditions will be `select` with different choice.
(Two columns of the same type so I have no problem to get them to that list.)

I want to make it look like a normal condition:

```
    if (...)
          // do something - select one column
    if (...)
          // do something - select another column
```

Now I have written in this way: (A is Parameter passed to the function and I check if A is one of the columns - if yes, select another column)

```
        var q1 = from stud in _context.temps
                where stud.a == A // this is first condition A==a
                select stud.b; // here selected column b
        var q2 = from stud in _context.temps
                where stud.b == A // this is second condition A==b
                select stud.a; // here selected column a
        List<temp> answer = q1.ToList();
        answer.AddRange(q2.ToList());
        return answer;
```

But that seemed too complex.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean - `select` and `where` are very different things. If you could give a more *concrete* example, it would really help.

Comment: You example doesn't illustrate the context of the "if" etc...?

Comment: I want to `select` different columns by two conditions in the `where` part without over tow times on the collection

Comment: Again... Please indicate where (in your example) the conditions (if) is involved

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean:

```
IQueryable<string> query;
if(foo) {
    query = from row in db.SomeTable
            where row.Whatever
            select row.SomeString;
} else if (bar) {
    query = from row in db.MaybeAnotherTable
            select row.AnotherString;
} ...

foreach(string s in query) ...
```

---

Edit based on your update:

If you have

```
 IQueryable<string> query1 = ..., query2 = ...;
 IQueryable<string> result = null;
```

Thn you could have multiple:

```
if(condition1) {
    result = result == null ? query1 : result.Concat(query1);
}
if(condition2) {
    result = result == null ? query2 : result.Concat(query2);
}
```

Comment: no, I mean two queries will be on the same table, but select another columns. As my example.

Comment: @zeevblu the "possibly different tables" is simply a more general case, but works the same. See also my edit, added after your example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **tertiary operator**, inside your `select` clause. See this code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> names = new Dictionary<string, string>();
names.Add("Saeed", "Neamati");
names.Add("Rasour", "Zabihi");
names.Add("Vahid", "Asefi");
names.Add("Mohsen", "Parmooz");

var query = from name in names
            select name.Key.StartsWith("V") ? name.Key : name.Value;
query.ToList().ForEach(n => {
    Console.WriteLine(n);
});
Console.ReadLine();
```

What it produces, is:

```
Nemati
Zabihi
Vahid
Parmooz
```

Comment: your example not good for me, but in this case i want to select all items that one of their strings equale to some string

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the example you provided, its seems that all you just need is an union. If that is the case, the following code would be what you are looking for.

```
var q1 = (from stud in _context.temps
        where stud.a == A
        select stud.b).Union 
            (from studb in _context.temps
            where stud.b == A
            select stud.a);

List<temp> answer = q1.ToList();
return answer;
```

Comment: what the different between your example and my example? Both query going down the list twice. you concatenate them with `Union` command and I with `AddRange`

Comment: @zeevblu: the example that you have presented will translate into two sql calls, one on q1.ToList() and one on q2.ToList(); the one that I've presented will do the same in one.